# Calculating sd of sample data from a regression line with a specific R^2 value in R

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a random data set from a regression line with a specific r-squared value in R. My idea is to create a random data set with rnorm(n, mean, sd), where each parameter in the function is estimated from the given regression line. However, I'm not sure how to calculate the sd value. Can someone help me with this issue?

Here are the parameters for the sample regression model:

y = a - b * x

a = 55.118, b = 1.218, r_sq = 0.47, n = 200, xmin = 23, xmax = 30

I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to calculate the sd value for generating the random data set. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the standard deviation (sd) of the random data set, you can use the formula for the residual standard error (RSE):

RSE = sqrt((1 - r_sq) * var(y))

Var(y) is the variance of the dependent variable y. Since the regression equation is (y = a - b * x), we can calculate the variance of y as follows:

var(y) = var(a) + x^2 * var(b) + 2 * x * cov(a, b)

Var(a) and var(b) are the variances of a and b and cov(a, b) is the covariance between a and b.

To estimate these values from the given regression line, you can try:

```
# Given parameters
a <- 55.118
b <- 1.218
r_sq <- 0.47
n <- 200
xmin <- 23
xmax <- 30

# Calculate variances and covariance
var_a <- (1 - r_sq) * var(rnorm(n))
var_b <- var_a / (xmax - xmin)^2
cov_ab <- -b * var_a / (xmax - xmin)

# Calculate RSE and sd
var_y <- var_a + (xmax^2 * var_b) + 2 * xmax * cov_ab
RSE <- sqrt((1 - r_sq) * var_y)
sd <- RSE / sqrt(n)
```

The sd value can then be used in the rnorm function to generate the random data set:

```
# Generate random data set
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
x <- seq(from = xmin, to = xmax, length.out = n)
y <- a - b * x + rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = sd)
```

Note that the set.seed function is used to ensure reproducibility of the random data set. You can change the seed value to generate a different random data set with the same parameters.

Comment: After executing your code, ```summary(lm(y~x))$r.squared``` returned ```0.998```, which is quite different from the original value (0.47). I believe that a regression model using the generated data should have a similar r-squared value with 0.47, but are they so different?

Comment: Hmm I see. 

There could be several reasons for this: 
1) The original regression model may not be a good fit for the data. It's possible that the data has a different underlying relationship between x and y, which could result in a different r-squared value. 

2) The sample size of 200 may not be enough to accurately estimate the parameters of the regression model, which could also contribute to the difference in r-squared values.

Perhaps you could evaluate the model using other metrics? Maybe  also check to see if the model is appropriate for the data. Sorry I wasn't super helpful.